# What does sufganiyot have to do with Christianity?

Tags: discussion

I was just awarded a hat called "Sufganiyot." Err...what does that have to do with Christianity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't.  It has to do with StackExchange.  It's [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) time again. Those hats apply to the entire StackExchange network, not just our site.

For the record, it appears to be an alternate spelling/play on words of a [Jelly doughnut associated with Hanukkah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufganiyah)

Comment: Oh OK. I thought the hats specifically applied to C.SE. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: "Sufganiyah" is singular; "sufganiyot" is plural.